# Object filtering and rearrange the order to my preference

Tags: javascript, php

I have a data coming from `php` encode and it looks like following when I console Log that is also displayed on a HTML table. Now I am trying to remove a few of the columns and rearrange the loop to my preferences but I can't. I can't even delete the properties. I know filter and delete are my functions but I am a bit confused on how to access property since obj['propertyName'] doesn't work:

```
0: {Product ID: "17", Product Name: "0.7 Carat Cushion Diamond", Carat: "0.70", Clarity: "VVS2", Shape: "Cushion"}
1: {Product ID: "19", Product Name: "0.9 Carat Round Diamond", Carat: "0.90", Clarity: "VS2", Shape: "Round"}
2: {Product ID: "21", Product Name: "1 Carat Radiant Diamond", Carat: "1.00", Clarity: "SI1", Shape: "Radiant"}
```

When I console

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myData[0]);
```

I get all the property names and the same loop will give me the values. But now I want to remove some property and their values and only show: Shape, Cut, Clarity for example.

I tried to create a new array

```
let headArr = ["Cut", "Shape", "Color", "Price"];
```

and pass that to my table generator but I still don't know how to match this array to my data so I get the new filtered data. I know I have a filter or delete but neither of those seems to work since I have a problem accessing the right position.

```
Console.log(myData[0])
```

returns property names. and

```
Console.log(Object.Keys(myData[0]));
```

return the 0, 1, 2.

How can I filter out columns such as Product ID, and rearrange the order to my preference?

```
      function generateTableHead(table, data) {
      let thead = table.createTHead();
      let row = thead.insertRow();

      for (let key of data) {
        let th = document.createElement("th");
        let text = document.createTextNode(key);
      // this is casual formalities 
        th.appendChild(text);
        row.appendChild(th);
      }
    }


    function generateTable(table, data) {
      for (let element of data) {
        let row = table.insertRow();
        for (key in element) {
          let cell = row.insertCell();
          let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
          cell.appendChild(text);
        }
      }
    }


let table = document.querySelector("table");

    // create a variable from values
    generateTable(table, myData);

    // create variable from keys
    generateTableHead(table, headArr);
```

Comment: The rearranging; you mean like select a column and tell JavaScript to sort it either ascending or descending?

Comment: A possible reason your `mydata` object is acting like an array is that the php object is an array.  Have you tried converting `mydata` to JSON first before you send it to the client?

Comment: yes myData comes from: var myData = <?php echo json_encode($json_array) ?>;

Comment: No rearenging I don't mean sorting, I meant telling it which columns come first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you may be running into us that `Product ID` and `Product Name` are not valid keys.

Assuming that `myData` in your example is an Array, here is one way to map the values to objects with just the keys you want:

```
let myData = [
{"Product ID": "17", "Product Name": "0.7 Carat Cushion Diamond", Carat: "0.70", Clarity: "VVS2", Shape: "Cushion"},
{"Product ID": "19", "Product Name": "0.9 Carat Round Diamond", Carat: "0.90", Clarity: "VS2", Shape: "Round"},
{"Product ID": "21", "Product Name": "1 Carat Radiant Diamond", Carat: "1.00", Clarity: "SI1", Shape: "Radiant"}
];

let filtered = myData.map(row => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(row).filter(it => { 
      let key = it[0]; 
      return ['Carat','Clarity','Shape'].indexOf(key) >= 0 
    })
  )
);
```

This is a "whitelist" approach. You could also use `Object.assign()` to copy each row and delete the properties you don't want (blacklist).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try and give this a more functional approach and see if I understand what your needs are:

You have an array.
You want to get only some properties (ex: Shape, Carat, Clarity) from all objects in array.
And then filter by only objects who have all of those properties.

You need a **pick** function that gets an array of props from an object.

Then a function that filters objects by those selected props, I called it **hasAll**.

And the result will be a concatenation of those two functions:

```js
let myData = [
{"Product ID": "17", "Product Name": "0.7 Carat Cushion Diamond", Carat: "0.70", Clarity: "VVS2", Shape: "Cushion"},
{"Product ID": "19", "Product Name": "0.9 Carat Round Diamond", Carat: "0.90", Clarity: "VS2", Shape: "Round"},
{"Product ID": "21", "Product Name": "1 Carat Radiant Diamond", Carat: "1.00", Clarity: "SI1", Shape: "Radiant"}
];

let headArr = ["Shape", "Clarity", "Carat"];


const pick = arr => obj => {
  const newObj = {};
  arr.forEach(key => {
    if(obj[key]) newObj[key] = obj[key];
  });
  return newObj;
}

const hasAll = arr => obj => {
  return arr.every(prop => prop in obj)
}

const result = myData
  .map(pick(headArr))
  .filter(hasAll(headArr))

console.log(result);
```

This approach is easier to read and gives you more clarity in case you want to change your program, and add/remove something in the composition.

Comment: Thanks but Am I able to target those filtered member individually? Since one of them is a link and I need it wrapped around a A tag?

Comment: But what do you want to wrap around an <a> tag? Since what you have in the `result` variable is an array of objects.

Comment: It would help if you run the code snippet above, see what you have in `result` and tell what your output would be! :)